# Insert into TextField using buttons from another widget - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I have a TextField that serves as a search bar where the user can use the built in Android/iOS keyboard to type but also has the possibility to insert a special characters in the search bar from a button. In a way the typing and the other insertion is combined into one string

*use case:* The user types *hell* in the search bar then presses the button widget the search bar value becomes : hellö

I set up everything but when I click the button nothing happens (the typing from the keyboard works fine)

Here's my code:

```
//I have this as a global variable
TextEditingController _searchInputControllor = TextEditingController();

//This is the TextField
class _SearchBarState extends State<SearchBar> { 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField( 
    enableInteractiveSelection: false,                     
    controller: _searchInputControllor,
    cursorColor: primaryDark,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 15.0),
      border: InputBorder.none,
      hintText: "Search...",
      suffixIcon: Material(                     
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 6.0,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0),),
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
          onTap: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.search, color: primaryDark,),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
  }
} 

//This is the button widget
//It is supposed to add to the search bar but nothing happens
class _SpecialCharState extends State<SpecialChar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: 40.0,
      child: FlatButton(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        textColor: Colors.black,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        splashColor: Colors.blue,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _searchInputControllor.text = _searchInputControllor.text + widget.btnVal.toLowerCase();
          });
        },
        child: Text(
          widget.btnVal
        ),
      )
    );
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A. No problem at all

I think your code is working well as I tried on my Android Phone [Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpVob.gif).

The text field is changed as I tap the buttons.

#### B. Change cursor position

Nonetheless, I add this code to make the cursor automatically placed on last character.

Rather than directly changed the text, we copy its value which contains selection.
Later we **offset** its selection by length of `newText`

```dart
void appendCharacters() {
  String oldText = _searchInputControllor.text;
  String newText = oldText + widget.btnVal.toLowerCase();

  var newValue = _searchInputControllor.value.copyWith(
    text: newText,
    selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
      offset: newText.length, //offset to Last Character
    ),
    composing: TextRange.empty,
  );

  _searchInputControllor.value = newValue;
}
```

so we can trigger the method with code below :

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ButtonTheme(
    minWidth: 40.0,
    child: FlatButton(
      onPressed: appendCharacters, // call a function
    ),
  );
}
```

### Working App Repository

You may look into this repo and build yourself. [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_text_field_control#demo)